# qt emitting signals how dipatching the signal works with concurrent threads

Tags: multithreading, qt

I wondering how qt decides which way of dispatch signals would work.

In http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads 
I found

`Auto Connection (default) If the signal is emitted in the thread which the receiving object has affinity then the behavior is the same as the Direct Connection. Otherwise, the behavior is the same as the Queued Connection.`

What is the meaning `affinity` in this case?

How Qt know which thread uses the methods of the object to prevent data corruption with signals? Is the `affinity` thread the one which creates the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each QObject is bound to a specific thread (queryable with the [`thread()` function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#thread)), by default the one where the object was created unless `moveToThread` was called.

Each object has the same thread as its parent.

Comment: If you say: "Each object has the same thread as its parent.", did this mean that child objects are created in another thread will "inherit" the thread "affinity" from the parent object?

Comment: You can't parent an object with an object on a different thread. As the docs for moveToThread state: "this function can only "push" an object from the current thread to another thread, it cannot "pull" an object from any arbitrary thread to the current thread."

Answer (score 0):

Thread affinity for an object is the thread in which that object is executing.

An object begins on the thread it is created and its thread affinity is that thread. Over its lifetime, it can be moved to a different thread, which would change the thread affinity.

When sending a signal, Qt looks at the thread affinity of the sending and receiving objects. If they have the same affinity (are running on the same thread) a direct connection is made.

However, if the two objects have different thread affinity (running on different threads), the sender places an event on the thread of the receiving object, which is using a queued connection